# Why use sessions for shopping carts?

Tags: python, django

Currently, I am learning Django and I am wondering why most courses use sessions for shopping carts instead of storing them to the database.

Comment: Out of topic question.

Comment: Usually sessions are not stored in a database but in memory, and thus faster to retrieve. Furthermore you typically want the `cart`s to expire easily if a user did not buy after a few months.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are relative to the user's current session and it may be convenient to erase all history in case the session expired/ user is logged out.